# Select rows where date > x AND date < y

Tags: sql-server, date, select, sql-server-ce, where-clause

I am developing an application and I need to select from 2 timePickers the greatest and smallest date to make a select * from utilizing the dates as conditions.

I have this:

```
var select = "SELECT * from inventario where ifechaCompra > "+diarioFecha1.Text+" and ifechaCompra < "+diarioFecha2.Text+"";
            SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexionDB"].ConnectionString);
            var dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(select, con);
            var commandBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            tablaInventario.ReadOnly = true;
            tablaInventario.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

The strange thing is that if instead of `< "+diarioFecha2.Text+"` I write manually a date it works, for example `'01/01/2014'`, but only on one of the two dates...
I don't get any error, it simply refreshes the dgv with no data at all.

PS: *I know I should be using parameters but when it comes to fill a dgv with that I don't know how to do it, only with insert statements, so if someone can help me with that I'd be very grateful..*

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just missing the single quotes:

```
var select = "SELECT * from inventario where ifechaCompra > '" + diarioFecha1.Text + "' and ifechaCompra < '" + diarioFecha2.Text + "'";

SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexionDB"].ConnectionString);
var dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(select, con);
var commandBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
var ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
tablaInventario.ReadOnly = true;
tablaInventario.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

I would also recommend to use dates with format yyyymmdd.